# Not able to Expand category after code for redirect in htaccess in Magento

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I have already set `yes` for 'Web Server Rewrites' at `System->Configuration->Web->Search Engine Optimization` for my Magento site. It's working for SEO friendly urls fine without **index.php** in url, but if URL entered manually with **index.php** then it does not redirect the URL removing the index.php and for this I added these 2 lines in `.htaccess`  files as:

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index.php(/[^\s\?]+)? [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %1/ [L,R=301]`

And after this it removes the **index.php** from manually entered URLs as well. So, this issue get solved.

But now I am facing the issue in back-end. I am not able to expand the category and some time I am not able to login in admin.

Please suggest solution **ASAP**.

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution and I put the code below in .htaccess and got resolved my issue.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(index.php/admin)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) $1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```